# How to get user access token dynamically for PAGE (no application)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, access-token

I am trying to get the number of likes my PAGE has at various times in the past using the FQL Insights API. To do this, I need a page access_token. The get a page access_token I need a user access_token. However, the only way I know how to get a user access token is to go here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and click "Get Access Token" and then copy and paste.

I can then get the PAGE access_token by running the following request:
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

And then I can get the number of likes using the following request:
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN&q=SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=PAGE_ID AND metric='page_fans' AND end_time=end_time_date('2013-05-15') AND period=period('lifetime')

So I can do everything dynamically and automatically EXCEPT getting my user access token. That's my big problem. The user access token that I get manually will expire and then I will have to get another one for my script to work. How can I get my user access token dynamically with PHP? My user account has the necessary permissions on the page, if it's of any consequence.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get a user access token dynamically, it defeats the purpose of manual user interaction.

You *can* use Scenario 5 as described at https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

> Exchange the short-lived user access token for a long-lived access token using the endpoint and steps explained earlier. By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages. This will also apply when querying with a non-expiring user access token obtained through the deprecated offline_access permission.

So basically, you should only need to authorize once as a user and keep the page token indefinitely.